# TwentyTwenty JQuery plugin not showing all images. When resizing window all images are shown

Tags: jquery, html, twentytwenty

I'm trying to build my first website with before / after slider images.
I'm using the **TwentyTwenty jQuery plugin**. When accessing the website, not all images are showing - when I reload or resize the window all are showing.

My website: http://www.nygreenstreets.com

TwentyTwenty plugin: https://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty

TwentyTwenty plugin on GitHub: https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty

For the images that are not showing I'm seeing a **height of 0px.**

`<div class="twentytwenty-container" style="height: 0px;">`

[Slider images correctly showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea7rb.png) / [Slider images not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMPmf.png) / [Only after resizing the window or reloading the page are all slider images showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxGpB.png)

The image sliders are in the following container:

```
<div class="twentytwenty-container">
<img src="index_files/images/160 W 43rd St 1.jpg" />
<img src="index_files/images/160 W 43rd St 2.jpg" /></div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $(".twentytwenty-container[data-orientation!='vertical']").twentytwenty({default_offset_pct: 0.5});
      $(".twentytwenty-container[data-orientation='vertical']").twentytwenty({default_offset_pct: 0.5, orientation: 'vertical'});
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you provide some code of yours

Comment: what do you mean by all images not seen, the plugin uses 2 images only to show the difference between them

Comment: Hi @satsvelke , I've added images to try to clarify the problem I'm having.

Comment: have you added all images in same container ? i.e twentytwenty-container ?

Comment: Yes, the containers used all have the same name. I've tried renaming them, same results.

Comment: try adding to different container, I think that is conflicting